# Copy command for the AWS Lambda Docker Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am attempting to deploy a AWS Lambda function with the docker image run time.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html).

The only difference is that my code resides in a `src` folder with other files and modules.

So I changed the Dockerfile CMD command to

```
CMD [ "src.main.handler" ]
```

But the AWS env does not seem to like that. I can find many examples of deploying single file applications but none about applications with an entrypoint in a folder.

Has anyone had any success with this before?

I should note that this application is not an api, it is aimed to do some processing and write to s3, so the docs where you can call the image locally through a port seem useless.

my dockerfile is

```
FROM            public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY            src ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY            requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN             pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

WORKDIR         ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD             [ "src.main.handler" ]
```

My file tree is as follows:

```
.
├── deploy
│   ├── backtesting
│   │   └── Dockerfile
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── aws
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── ssm.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── ssm.py
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── database_connector.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── database_connector.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── streams
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── athena_stream.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── database_stream.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── model_stream.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── owned_horse_stream.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── athena_stream.py
│   │   ├── database_stream.py
│   │   ├── manual_trigger_stream.py
│   │   └── owned_horse_stream.py
│   ├── utils
│   │   ├── helpers.py
│   │   ├── market_book_filters.py
│   │   └── pricing_helpers.py
```

This is the error I get when testing locally

````
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'src.main': No module named 'src'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}```
````

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. "does not seem to like that." - what does it even mean? Any errors? Where is your Dockerfile?

Comment: Where my dockerfile is irrelevant in the scope of a lambda deployment. It is stored in ECR if you are wondering.

Comment: The error itself is that `ImportError: No module named src` due to the package not being found.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was solved by @thesynde mentioning that I was infact importing all the files inside of my src folder and not the folder itself.

This was fixed by changing the copy command to

```
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
```

and it working.